# How can I combine the dataframes returned by a function efficiently in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function which returns many values on every run but I am interested in dataframe being returned. I am currently using a list to store dataframes and then at the end I use pd.concat to convert all the dfs in to a single df. It's working fine but when I try to push this code for review I face linting errors "too many local variables'. There's no way I can deal with other varibales so, is there a way more efficient to store these dataframes and then later convert it to a single frame.

Currently, the code is something like this:

```
df_list = []

....

_, _, df = function_call()

df_list.append(df)

....

df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)
```

Comment: Where is stored the dataframes? csv, excel, html? Show us a part of your df and how much dfs and rows will be concat.

Comment: This dataframe is getting stored inside big query. The dfs could range from 10 to 100s to even 1000s. Even with the rows, could go into 100,000.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to store the argument values to pass to the dataframe generating function in a list, and then use a generator expression in the `pd.concat` call?

Something like this:

```py
kwargs_list = []

kwargs = {'arg1': val1, 'arg2': val2}
kwargs_list.append(kwargs)
...

df = pd.concat(function_call(**kwargs) for kwargs in kwargs_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the function also return other values apart from the dataframe. I should have mentioned this in the question as well.

Comment: do you need the other values? If you don't need them adding a lambda function will solve the problem

Comment: Yes, other values are being used to achieve something else. I just need to find a better way of doing this, so that I can reduce the count of variables.